# Is it possible to reverse final single number output of multiple XOR and bits shifting operations

Tags: javascript, xor

I have a code written in JS of parsing **x,y,z** into 1 number.

Is it possible to somehow revert the operation and get **x,y,z** back by only knowing the final number and the operations made on it?
I have hardcoded **x,y,z**  in the rever function in order to test the reverse process and it works. But what I need is getting the **x,y,z** back from the parsedOutput

```
let ParseWithXor = () => {
  let x = 25;
  let y = 8;
  let z = 110;
  let finalOutput = 0;
  finalOutput = finalOutput ^ (x << 9);
  console.log(` finalOutput ^ (${x} << 9) = ${finalOutput}`);
  finalOutput = finalOutput ^ (y << 5);
  console.log(` finalOutput ^ (${y} << 5) = ${finalOutput}`);
  finalOutput = finalOutput ^ z;
  console.log(`finalOutput ^ ${z} = ${finalOutput}`);
  return finalOutput;
};

let Revert = (parsedOutput) => {
  console.log(parsedOutput);
  parsedOutput = parsedOutput ^ 110;
  console.log(parsedOutput);
  parsedOutput = parsedOutput ^ (8 << 5);
  console.log(parsedOutput);
  parsedOutput = parsedOutput ^ (25 << 9);
  console.log(parsedOutput);
};

ParseWithXor();
console.log("-------------------------------------");
Revert(13166);


finalOutput ^ (25 << 9) = 12800
finalOutput ^ (8 << 5) = 13056
finalOutput ^ 110 = 13166
--------------------------------------
13166
13056
12800
0
```

Comment: I made a snippet  - had to remove a double declaration of finalOutput

Comment: LOL: It reminded me of this xkcd: [It's okay, we can just feed the one-pixel image into an AI upscaler and recover the original image, or at least one that's just as cool.](https://xkcd.com/2671/)

Comment: @mplungjan LOL: had a nice laugh on that +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you xor an integer with integer twice you will get original number

```
(a ^ b) ^ b = a
```

it does not matter the order of xor operations

```
a ^ b ^ c  = b ^ a ^ c
```

so if you have

```
a ^ c0 ^ c1 ^ c2 = b
```

then

```
a = b ^ c0 ^ c1 ^ c2
```

so the answer is yes you just xor back in reverse order to obtain the sub results... or in any order if you want just original value.

so you have:

```cpp
w0 = 0;
w1 = w0 ^ (x << 9);
w2 = w1 ^ (y << 5);
w3 = w2 ^ (z     );
```

I would revers it like this:

```cpp
w3 = ...;

// x,y,z from w(i)   |   w(i) from x,y,z
// ---------------------------------------
z = (w3 ^ w2);       |  w2 = w3 ^ (z     ); 
y = (w2 ^ w1) >> 5;  |  w1 = w2 ^ (y << 5); 
x = (w1 ^ w0) >> 9;  |  w0 = w1 ^ (x << 9); 

// x,y,z from w3,w0 but x,y,z must not overlap bits
// z = <0,31> 
// y = <0,15>
// x = <0,(max/512)-1> 
// ----------------------------------------------
w = w0 ^ w3;
z = w & 31; w >>= 5;
y = w & 15; w >>= 4;
x = w;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention there is also bits shifting operations, I Edited the post. I did not quite understood from your answer how do I extract X,Y,Z if I don`t know them at the revert function

Comment: Again, Maybe I did not understand what you meant to do or I missing something, But on this assignment: w2 = w3 ^ (z     ); your not suppose to know what Z is

Comment: No actually I dont know what w0,w1,w2 in the Revert method . I Know them only in the process of ParseWithXor method . In the Revert method I only know W3 in your case which passed as a parameter and the operations made to achive it without knowing w0,w1,w2 or X,Y,Z in my case. Im not sure it even possible so thats what I asked.

Comment: @att than see the last version of reversal ... but: `z<=31; y<=15;` !!!

Comment: Perfect !! @Spektre

Comment: @ATT if the `x,y,z` overlap bits then there will be multiple answers satisfying the `w0,w3` and you would need to search for all or just pick one .... however I think the reverse equation would no longer work and you would need to resolve to `O(n^2)` brute force

Comment: Is there also a simple solution for revert bit shifting? example: 
11297 >> 8 = 44,

44 << 8 = 11264

Comment: @ATT no if you loose bits ...  `11297dec = 10110000100001bin` if you cut 8 lowest bits you lost the shift outed bits ... so in 44 you simply do not have the information left that would only work for numbers that are multiple of 256 (all 8 lowest bits are zero)...